# Why are deleted branches not removed on the remote after pushing?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, dvcs, git-flow

I am using `git-flow` and what it does is that it deletes my `feature/abc` branch whenever I do :

```
git flow feature abc finish
```

It deletes the `feature/abc` branch after merging it with `develop` branch. After that I push my `develop` branch.

```
git push origin develop
```

Now, on the remote I am able to see the `feature/abc` branch, but not locally. So, does that means it deleted from local repo and that delete didn't got carried to remote ?

In my understanding :

- Since git is distributed, so the whole repo exists on all machines.
- So, if I do a change in my local repo and push it to a remote.
- Then, all my changes should be pushed to the remote, including the delete.

Conflict:

- How can local and remote git repo be different after a push.

=> Assume I am the sole developer on the code.

**Update**

My question is that I deleted the branch locally post merge. then I pushed the branch to which I merged, then why didn't that reflect on the remote ?
Since, GIT is DVCS and should be identical on push / pull. [ Considering I am the only dev ]

I didn't asked to create it either. It made the branch made my changes, merged it back then deleted the branch and pushed my updated develop branch. So, if it automatically detects the creation of those branches then why not the deletion ?

Comment: you need to have something like `git pull upstream master` or your branchname in place of `master` on other systems to make the changes reflect on the other system on which you have configured git.

Comment: In my understanding `push` pushes everything including the other branches to the remote. It makes the 2 repos identical. I just merges the branch being talked about - for others it pushes the changes.

Comment: Ok I got your question now. Here you have to notice that you have just pushed the develop branch but not anything else. So remote doesnt know anything that you have deleted feature/abc branch. So its still seen in remote.

Comment: Sorry i had to delete my answer as your argument doesnt make any sense(on the way Git is created & also saying your log is classified). You might have done push somewhere while working with the branch you deleted so it was reflected in repo. Read the whole GIT man pages if you wana inspect the behaviour!

Comment: You mean to say, it should have deleted the remote branches if I did what I am saying ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since, GIT is DVCS and should be identical on push / pull.

No, that’s not really true. It is distributed so each repository within the net more or less contains the same data, but only more or less. When you use push and pull, you explicitely specify what is being pushed.

`git push remote branch` only pushes the the branch pointer `branch` to the remote repository and transfers all commits the remote repository needs to construct it, but not more. This means that only the commit the branch points to and all parents are actually pushed until the remote repository finds a common parent that it already has (in the worst case, this is the special zero-commit, i.e. the empty parent).

In the same way `git pull remote branch` only fetches the changes required to construct the remote branch `remote/branch` locally.

To really get all commits, you can use `git fetch`, and to push all local branches you can use `git push --all`. But again, it only fetches/pushes the commits necessary to construct the branches (or tags), not everything the repository has.

Now, when you push branches to the remote repository it will update only those branches you actually pushed, so when you deleted a local remote and push with `--all`, then only your local branches are pushed, and that does not include the deleted one. So your local Git does no longer know which branches you locally deleted (because they were merged) and as such cannot give that information to the remote repository automatically. What it can do however is tell the remote repository every branch it locally has so the remote can figure out which was deleted. You do this by using the option `--prune`. Note however that this removes all branches that do not exist locally, so it might make problems when working with multiple users that push different branches but don't pull the other ones (I actually never tested that though).

The best thing is obviously to remove locally deleted branches directly:

```
git push remote :branch
```

Comment: Very well said. You said it `pull` / `push` only what is required to create the branch commits. Can you provide some references to support that ? If that is the case - The confusion is resolved.

Comment: Uhm, I guess I could look in the source to tell what internal commands are invoked, but the documentation of git push actually says it itself: *“Updates remote refs using local refs, while sending objects necessary to complete the given refs.”* So only refs (name and 40 characters for the commit id) are pushed and all necessary objects (commits, trees and blobs) are sent to complete them.

Comment: What happens If I only do `git pull` [ No remote and branch name ]

It gives `warning` but pulls something - Does it pulls everything ?

Comment: `git pull` without any parameters will use the default tracking remote and branch of the branch you are currently on. It gets those information from the git config values `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge`.